# Which form of English (US or UK) should be used for Elsevier journal publication?

Tags: publications, journals, elsevier

I am intending to write a journal paper for Elsevier Gait & Posture publication, but so far I found contradictory answers to the above question.

Answer (score 16):

Check the journal's guidelines. Different Elsevier journals have different preferences. Some are happy with either American or British English, as long as you are consistent.

Answer (score 11):

This type of information can usually be found in the instructions for authors. The [Gait & Posture instructions](https://www.elsevier.com/journals/gait-and-posture/0966-6362/guide-for-authors) say:

> Please write your text in good English (American or British usage is accepted, but not a mixture of these).